# Prevent Method call without Exception using @PreAuthorize Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-security

We are using Spring Security 3. We have a custom implementation of **PermissionEvaluator** that has this complex algorithm to grant or deny access at method level on the application. To do that we add a **@PreAuthorize** annotation to the method we want to protect (obviously). Everything is fine on that. However the behavior that we are looking for is that if a **hasPermission** call is denied, the protected method call only needs to be skipped, instead we are getting a 403 error each time that happens.

Any ideas how to prevent that?

---

You can find a different explanation of the problem here; [AccessDeniedException handling during methodSecurityInterception](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=19589)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use custom `MethodSecurityInterceptor`, which calls the `AccessDecisionManager` (implicitly, bu calling super's method)  and decides than whether to proceed with a method call.

```
package com.myapp;

public class MyMethodSecurityInterceptor extends MethodSecurityInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        Object result = null;
        try {
             InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(mi);             
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            // access denied - do not invoke the method and  return null
            return null;
        }

        // access granted - proceed with the method invocation
        try {
            result = mi.proceed();
        } finally {
            result = super.afterInvocation(token, result);
        }

        return result;        
        }
}
```

Setting up the app context is a bit tricky: since you can not use `<sec:global-mathod-security>` in this case, there is a need to define an explicit AOP configuration (and create most of the corresponding bean structure the original tag does by default):

```
<aop:config>
    <!-- Intercept all relevant methods -->
    <aop:pointcut id="myMethods"
                  expression='execution(* com.myapp.myService+.*(..))'/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="mySecurityInterceptor" pointcut-ref="myMethods"/>
</aop:config>

<!-- Configure custom security interceptor -->
<bean id="mySecurityInterceptor"
      class="com.myapp.MyMethodSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="validateConfigAttributes" value="false"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Configure AccessDecisionManager -->
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure AuthenticationManager as you wish -->
<!-- ........................................... -->
```

Comment: I ended up doing something quite more simple, I just added an advice over the MethodSecurityInterceptor that catches the exception with an @Around so that the propagation past that point is prevented. That way I could avoid configuring Spring Security by foot, which is very convoluted. However what you propose is the canonical way to do it and it works.

Comment: Very nice! I wonder if there is any way we can change behavior of beforeInvocation() (using AOP) to check user's permissions on specific method (that OP wants to protect) and replace mi by a dummy MethodInvocation instance instead of worrying about AccessDeniedException.

Comment: @Chepech @Around solution seems very simple and elegant. If you update the @Around code in question, I will gladly vote it up.

Comment: @Ritesh, sure, you can always protect a method with a pointcut. The good side of the proposed solution is an ability to use the full power of SpringSecurity infrastructure for an authentication decision making.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a way to prevent the AccessDeniedException.
However this doesnt solves the problem. The excecution of the rest of the code now contunies normaly, however the secured method call is not prevented even when hasPermission returns false.

This is how I managed to prevent the AccessDeniedException from stoping everything:

You need to implement an [AccessDecisionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionManager.html) where you prevent the **AccessDeniedException** propagation. Thats the easy part. Mine looks like this:

```
public class SkipMethodCallAccessDecisionManager extends AffirmativeBased {
    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes){
        try{
            super.decide(authentication, object, configAttributes);
        }catch(AccessDeniedException adex){
            logger.debug("Access Denied on:" + object);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the tricky part... setting up the application context.

```
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="skipMethodCallAccessDecisionManager "/>

<bean id="skipMethodCallAccessDecisionManager" class="com.application.auth.vote.SkipMethodCallAccessDecisionManager ">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter">
                <constructor-arg ref="expressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice"/>
            </bean>
            <!-- Insert RoleVoter if required -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>         
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="expressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice">
    <property name="expressionHandler" ref="expressionHandler"/>
</bean>
```

Any ideas on how to prevent the method from being called without stopping everything?

Comment: this won't work. As shown by @Boris Kirzner, mi.proceed() will be called if there is no exception in beforeInvocation(mi)

Comment: @Ritesh - I know it doesn't work, I added this to document what I was doing to provide clues to people that read the question since no one answered this for almost 1 month. I state this fact in the answer.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was old question. I checked it when I was googling to find a similar solution.

Comment: @Ritesh  - No problem man... I also posted the advice code as you suggested.

Comment: Chepech +1 to your answer and +1 to your question :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the code for the advice solution I implemented.

This is the Aspect code:

```
@Aspect
public class AccessDeniedHaltPreventionAdvice {
private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AccessDeniedHaltPrevention.class);

@Around("execution(@org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize * *(..))")
public Object preventAccessDeniedHalting(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
    Object retVal = null;
    try{
        retVal = pjp.proceed();
    }catch(AccessDeniedException ade){
        logger.debug("** Access Denied ** ");
    }catch(Throwable t){
        throw t;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

}

You may need to add a  **@Order** annotation to ensure that the advice is able to catch the exception (usually a  **@Order(value=1)** does the work). Also you'll need to add the aspectj autorproxy to the App context:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

You may also need to play around with the **@Around** parameters, In my case it was pretty simple as we are securing everything with **PreAuthorize** annotations.

This the simplest way I could figure out. However, I strongly recommend people to use the solution suggested by Boris Kirzner.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: I tried adapting this to use on a PostAuthorize annotation, unfortunately it didn't work so well, as I end up receiving "javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly" which is strange because I do see it swallowing up the exception, which is generally what tickles the transaction into Rollback mode.