# Spring Security - Prevent AccessDeniedException from stopping application normal flow

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Secuirty 3 with ACL module. I'm securing the methods with **@PreAuthentication** annotations using a custom **PermissionEvaluator**. Its working fine, however every time the **PermissionEvaluator** returns an **ACCESS_DENIED** an **AccessDeniedException** is thrown at some point and this stops the application execution. The desired behaivore will be that when the **PermissionEvaluator** returns and **ACCESS_DENIED**, the secured method call is only prevented (skipped) and the rest of the application keeps running normally. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Method call without Exception using @PreAuthorize Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621394/prevent-method-call-without-exception-using-preauthorize-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each call where you want this to happen in a `try...catch`, you can get this behavior. Basically, since it's an exception, any normal exception handling will apply to it. If your application can handle that exception and continue normally, then do exactly that!

---

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
// The 1st method that could be denied but you want to continue execution after
try {
    // Call method A that will throw the exception
} catch (/*The exception you expect to be thrown and want to continue after*/){}


// The 2nd method that could be denied but you want to continue execution after
try {
    // Call method B that will throw the exception
} catch (/*The exception you expect to be thrown and want to continue after*/){}

etc.
```

Yes, it does add a lot of overhead to calling those methods, but it is a fairly simple way of allowing execution to continue after an exception is raised.

I would also argue that it is also more correct, since the calling code *does* know how to deal with those exceptions. This also doesn't require any additional Spring configuration, which means that the code behavior remains closer to the default and does not rely on external configurations to determine it's behavior.

Comment: The problem with that is that it then allows the method call no matter the result of the PermissionEvaluator, so its basically like disabling the security

Comment: Check this answer, thats basicly the way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621394/prevent-method-call-without-exception-using-preauthorize-annotation

Comment: @Chepech - I updated my answer with an example and a justification.